# I am trying to create 2 cubes, with one mirroring the other. Instead it appears to create one cube that is always connected to the center!

Tags: modeling

This is my first attempt at creating a character using blender. I am finished with the body, and now I am trying to add hands. I put my cursor where I want the origin to be and then pressing Shift+A to create a cube, which I would hope would also create an identical cube mirrored across the center. Instead, it seems as though these two cubes always have to be connected in the center. Any suggestions? This is my first day using blender so forgive me for not knowing the terminology. [image]

Comment: You are in front view looking at the XZ plane. The mirror is the YZ plane going thru 0. Currently one face of the cube is on the mirror plane, as answered below, select all verts and  move away from the mirror to have 2 distinct mirrored cubes.

Answer (score 0):

Shift A amd create a cube. move it to right along x axis beyond the center line. Make sure 3d cursor is at world origin by pressing shift + s and select cursor to world origin. With your cube still selected in object mode press F3 and search for set origin and select origin to 3d cursor. Select mirror modifier and make sure your axis is x going by your picture

Comment: If he is setting the 3D cursor where he wants the center of the mirror to be, it's not necessarily the world origin he's talking about. So it would be much easier (like he already does) to place the cursor where he wants to add the cube, then go into edit mode and move the cube there. This way the origin stays where it is and where he wanted it to be (to maybe add more objects right at the same position) and he doesn't need to reset cursor, reset origin etc.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have clipping turned on in modifier settings which causes shapes to merge at the center. Just uncheck The *Clipping* Checkbox and it should be fine.
[image]

With Clipping
[image]
Without Clipping
[image]

Note:You Have To Turn Off Clipping Before you move the cube in editmode otherwise it will retain its stretched shape

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)